# How to change c++ code to run on 64bit machine?

Tags: c++, compilation, x86

I have an old research project in my lab, which was made in 2008/9. It was initially created on WinXP, and coded in C++. My professor now asks me to 'restore' it. I managed to compile on Win7 64-bit, but when I run it, it says

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

What should I do to make it run on 64-bit machine? I understand that I can run a 32-bit OS on a VM, but the professor doesn't want that. Also take in consideration that the code is HUGE, so I cannot rewrite it.

Comment: This looks like a message generated by some kind of preprocessort check (`#if ...`) followed by `#error`. Find the piece of code containing the above text. (By doing a full-text search on the source files.) Inspect the code section for the exact kind of check being done there. If that doesn't give you any ideas, add it to your question. As of now, you might be facing anything from just tweaking the preprocessor test to major refactoring. We can't tell.

Comment: I hope it was 64bit-clean when you wrote it in the first place, otherwise you'll be stuck with making 32bit builds of it.  (potential problems include things like assuming that a pointer can be stored in an `int`.)  MS kept `long` as 32bit so code that assumed `int` and `long` are interchangeable can keep making that non-portable assumption in the x86-64 Windows ABI.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an preprocessor check -- the OP said they'd "managed to compile" the program.  This sounds like a run-time check.  Possibly linking with the wrong version (32/64-bit) of a library?

Comment: You know you can run 32bit binaries on a 64bit OS, right?  Do you need to use your code on data sets too big for a 32b program to handle?

Comment: As @AJNeufeld stated, this seems the [old known windows error popup](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HUYaXPJDKS8/UijXDzMH6xI/AAAAAAAABnE/-o9gmL-ojjc/s640/Untitled.png). You must have a 32 bit dll messing with  you, verify what are you linking to in the project properties.